# How to load Beat Saber 1.19 mods on 1.20?

Tags: beat-saber

Pretty much, I have just updated my Beat Saber to 1.20, and I LOVE it. But, how do I use saber factory? I used it on 1.19, but how do I load it on 1.20?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that'll break the game, since they've implemented so much new contents. I suppose you wait for the mod to get updated. I'm sure they'll be soon get proper update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mods don't exist for 1.20 yet.
You don't.

Answer (score 0):

Beat Saber updates frequently break compatibility with mods. Luckily for you, Saber Factory was [updated on March 16th](https://github.com/ToniMacaroni/SaberFactory/releases/tag/2.5.1) to work with Beat Saber 1.20. It hasn't been uploaded to [BeatMods](https://beatmods.com/#/) yet, so it won't appear in [ModAssistant](https://github.com/Assistant/ModAssistant/releases/latest). You'll need to manually download and install the mod to your `Plugins` folder.

Alternatively, you can use mods that haven’t been updated by downgrading your version of Beat Saber using [Beat Saber Legacy](https://bslegacy.com/). (Disclaimer: I am a Patreon supporter for Beat Saber Legacy)